# How to make content exclusion in XSD?

Tags: xsd

When defining an element in DTD, there is a feature to exclude elements from its content model, for example:

```
<!ELEMENT i - - (%inline;) -(i)>
```

Instead of repeating the content model for each element separately, we just list similar elements as a model group (entity in DTD) and exclude what we don't need in some elements.

In XML Schema I can use complex types with inheritance and/or model groups to share the same content model between elements, but to exclude some elements I have to repeat the whole content model just not adding unwanted elements. Too much code to type, to read, to edit...

Is there another, simple and beautiful way to implement this in XML Schema, or I should use RelaxNG or look for tools for generating schemas? Shortly, in XML Schema terminology, I want (and really need) something like derivation by restriction, but not duplicating the content model.

Answer (score 1):

An `assert` such as

```
not(./*/local-name-from-QName(node-name(.)) = 'put-name-to-exclude-here')
```

may do the trick, but requires XML Schema 1.1.

For example, using a group (i.e., this is technically not exactly derivation by restriction):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:group name="base">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="c" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>
    <xs:complexType name="excluding-a">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:group ref="base"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:assert test="not(./*/local-name-from-QName(node-name(.)) = 'a')"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="root" type="excluding-a"/>
</xs:schema>
```

This will be valid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <b/>
  <c/>
</root>
```

And this will be invalid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <a/>
  <b/>
  <c/>
</root>
```

Another approach that explicitly uses derivation involves derivation by extension, as unintuitive as it may sound (restriction would require repeating all elements). This is because the semantics of XML Schema regarding derivation is not strict in terms of value space inclusion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:complexType name="base">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="c" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="derived">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="base">
                <xs:assert test="not(*/local-name-from-QName(node-name(.)) = 'a')"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="root" type="derived"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Oh, looks nice! I'll test it tonight. Version 1.1 and groups for using inside classes is exactly what I want.